# proving property of fourier series

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Let be $f$ real and $ f(t)= f(-t) $

How can I show that the fourier coefficents come to $$ \hat{f} (n)= \frac{1}{ \pi} \int_0^{ \pi} f(t) \cos (nt) dt $$

I know I can rewrite $f$ as 
$$ f(t)= \frac{a_o}{2} + \sum_{k=1}^{ \infty} (a_k \cos(kt) + b_k \sin(kt))$$

Comment: Use orthogonality of the cosine and sine functions: if you calculate $\int_{0}^{\pi} f(t) cos(nt)dt$ and use $f(t) = a_{0}/2+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(a_{k}\cos(kt)+b_{k}\sin(kt))$, you conclude the result,

Comment: Use even and oddness property of sine and cosine. Yes you may need that the sines are pairwise orthogonal too.

Answer (score 1):

You did a *rewriting*, now do it again for

$$ f(-x)\,\,=\,\,\ldots $$

Done? Then take into account @mathreadler reminder (see their comment above) when you compare the two rewritings since $\ f(-t)=f(t)$.  Done? *Great!*